# In LWUIT, a white rectangular background appears when the button is pressed, how to remove it?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-button

Using LWUIT, I have a `Form` (form1) which contains a `Button` (see the silver arrow at the bottom of the `Form` in the left image below). This `Button` is constructed using an image which has a transparent background to give the effect of a non-rectangular `Button`. When the `Button` is pressed it shows another `Form` (form2).

But unfortunately, when the user presses this `Button`, a white rectangular background appears for a few milliseconds in the background of the image. see the right image below:

[image: Before Pressing the button]
[image: After Pressing the button]

The question is: 
**How may I prevent this white rectangle from being appeared after pressing the `Button` ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have modified the state of the button when it is selected or unselected. You also have to modify pressed style. 
You can do it with `button.getPressedStyle()`

Try:

```
button.getPressedStyle().setBorder(null);
button.getPressedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
```